# I get an error 19, failed to resume with device 0:007

Tags: suspend

I've searched the web for answers to this, and the only other question that looks exactly like mine concerned Ubuntu 13.10 (8 months ago), with no answer to date. I'm on 14.04. I experience no system problem after resume, but I do see the error 19 flash on the black screen just before waking. It points to device 0:007 as the problem.

Any suggestions? What's the problem with it?

Comment: Are you actually having a problem or are you just seeing the error?

Comment: I am just seeing the error, but wondering why. My system does seem to resume a tad slow given its specs, and I thought maybe it had something to do with that error.                            -Computer-
Processor  : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory  : 8049MB (1898MB used)
Operating System  : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
-Display-
Resolution  : 1920x1080 pixels

Comment: Double check the device code (0:007), and look for it in lspci or dmesg with `lspci | grep 0:007` or `dmesg | grep 0:007`